# Starting screen in detached mode doesn't source environment

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, gnu-screen

I would like to start `screen`sessions in a detached state so that they terminate once the script finishes **and** so that I can write a script to execute multiple `screen` sessions without me having to manually, one by one, start each session and then detach, before moving onto to the next screen session.

This script depends on certain environment variables being set. Normally, when I run this script outside of `screen`, in a regular `bash` shell, I simply have these environment variables set in my `.bash_profile` file.

Furthermore, when I start screen in a non-detached state and put in my `.screenrc` file:

`shell -$SHELL`

then I also have no problems.

The issue only arises when I perform `screen -dm` then my script fails to run as the environment I need is not set.

How can I tell screen to refer to the `.screenrc` file when starting in a detached state such that it ultimately sources my `.bash_profile` on startup?

**UPDATE**

When I perform `screen -dmL env` I can see that some but not all of my environment variables are present.

Comment: Two questions: 1) When you start the `screen` session in attached mode, do you then start the script from the shell prompt? 2) In the detached scenario, do you start your script with something like `screen -dm myScript`?

Comment: 1) Yes, from the shell prompt. 2) Also correct, I start in detached mode like `screen -dmL myScript`. The -L flag logs the output.

Comment: Also, do you see any difference between the environment from `screen env` and `screen -d -m -L env`? I suspect they'll be the same, and so getting your script to run with `screen ./myScript` will be sufficient for `screen -d -m -L ./myScript` to work, but will also be easier to debug.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is that when starting `screen` in detached mode, `screen` does not start a login shell or an interactive shell, and so your `.bash_profile` is not sourced (see the "INVOCATION" section of `man bash` for an explanation of what files are sourced when on start up).  Note that the leading `-` in your

```
shell -$SHELL
```

setting means the shell will always be started as a login shell, and so `.bash_profile` will be sourced.

Some possible solutions to your problem:

1. don't start `screen` in detached state.  Note that `screen` terminates when the script finishes when started in the usual way, if the script is given as a command.  E.g., for the script `test.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   for n in `seq 1 5`; do
     echo $n
     sleep 1
   done
   ```

   doing `screen ./test.sh` runs the script and terminates after 5 seconds.
2. manually source your `.bash_profile` in the script you're running in screen. I.e. add

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   to the beginning of your script, `MyScript`.

## Update 1

I still suspect the problem is that your `.bash_profile` is not being loaded, so let's be sure your `.screenrc` *is* being loaded.  Try adding

```
screen touch /tmp/when-was-screen-rc-sourced
```

to the end of your `~/.screenrc` and then do

```
screen MyScript
```

and then

```
ls -lt --full-time /tmp
```

Try starting screen a few different ways and see if `~/.screenrc` is really failing to load.

Similarly, you can add a line

```
touch /tmp/when-was-bash-profile-sourced
```

to the end of your `~/.bash_profile` to see when that is loaded.

## Update 2

Here is an example that shows that `screen` does run your script when you have the line

```
screen touch /tmp/when-was-screen-rc-sourced
```

at the end of your `~/.screenrc`.

Here is the test file `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/when-did-test-sh-start
for n in `seq 1 5`; do
  echo $n
  sleep 1
done
touch /tmp/when-did-test-sh-finish
```

Here is the evidence. Running

```
$ touch /tmp/when-did-we-start; screen -d -m ./test.sh; sleep 6; ls -ltr --full-time /tmp | tail -n4
```

gives output

```
-rw------- 1 collins collins    0 2013-11-06 14:43:03.643564802 -0800 when-did-we-start
-rw------- 1 collins collins    0 2013-11-06 14:43:03.659565385 -0800 when-was-screen-rc-sourced
-rw------- 1 collins collins    0 2013-11-06 14:43:03.671565892 -0800 when-did-test-sh-start
-rw------- 1 collins collins    0 2013-11-06 14:43:08.707770194 -0800 when-did-test-sh-finish
```

So, I still think the problem is related to your `~/.bash_profile` (or
whatever defines your missing env vars) not being loaded.

## Update 3

At this point it might be easier to understand exactly what you're
trying to accomplish, and then come up with a better way to do it. To
do this it would be helpful for you to provide a minimal example
script that illustrates your problem (i.e. it works when you run it
directly, or manually after starting screen, but not when run directly
via `screen ./example.sh` or `screen -d -m ./example.sh`).

But, in the mean time, here's another potential workaround (did you
ever try my second original suggestion above, of just sourcing your
`~/.bash_profile` in your script directly?):

Run your script with bash, explicitly making bash interactive
and/or a login shell.  E.g. for an interactive login shell do

```
screen -d -m bash -i -I ./MyScript
```

See
[here](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)
for a nice summary of what files bash loads in what modes. According
to `man bash`, the `bash -i -I` combination should make bash run your
script in interactive login mode, and hence `~/.bash_profile` should
get sourced.

Comment: The problem remains if I do `screen ./MyScript`. I simply don't understand why starting screen without supplying a script, that is just `screen` (no significant arguments) lets me run `MyScript` but any other convenient form and it appears `screen` ignores the `.screenrc` file leaving me screwed.

Comment: Are you sure your `.screenrc` is not being loaded? I still believe your problem is related to `.bash_profile` not being loaded. I'll edit my answer with a suggestion for debugging this ...

Comment: I believe the `.screenrc` is not being loaded. I tried putting in my `.screenrc` file `echo "Hello world"` after the `shell -$SHELL` line. I see this echo after terminating a screen session that I start attached. The `screen -dm` attempts do not output this echo. --- Let me try your update suggestion and get back to you as well.

Comment: Please try the `touch` version also. It's more convincing because it does not depend on what screen thinks stdout is when it runs the `echo`.

Comment: The `touch` approach has problems though. Adding `screen touch /tmp/when-was-screen-rc-sourced` to my `.screenrc` results in screen terminating immediately after executing the `touch` command. This is both for running `screen` and starting an attached session or doing `screen -dm MyScript`. Although I can confirm that the touched file is created...

Comment: On my system the `screen` still runs the supplied script before terminating.  I'll add an example file that demonstrates this to my answer.  Please try running it on your system.

Answer (score 2):

No need for ~/.screenrc
Make your ~/.bash_profile one line: `source ~/.bashrc`
Put your aliases and environemnt variables in ~/.bashrc

In ~/.bashrc, write code like this:

```
alias myalias="echo ThisWorks"

run_myalias_in_bg_screen (){
    screen -dmS mytestscreen bash -c 'exec bash'
    screen -r mytestscreen -p0 -X stuff "myalias"
    screen -r mytestscreen -p0 -X eval "stuff \015"
}
```

Now test it out in your terminal

```
$ run_myalias_in_bg_screen
$ screen -r mytestscreen
```